# Making combobox_selectedIndexChanged work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

I have a web page that on page load loads data into drop down lists and the user has the option to change the values if they wish too. How do I make it so everytime they change the value it will save it and resend it to the database? So far all I have is this:

```
Private Sub cboCure_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboCure.SelectedIndexChanged

    cboCure.SelectedItem.Text = CStr(sender)
    ...database functions using cboCure.SelectedItem.Text

End Sub
```

I don't know if this is enough information to help out at all, if it's not just lemme know... I don't really know what else to put in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `autopostback` property of your combobox to `true`. So that, whenever a change happens; you can check if `if(ispostback)` and have your code to do the insertion of changed data in DB.

Comment: Do I do the check to see `f(ispostback)` in that `Sub` or on `Page_Load`

Comment: @bbesase, in `page_load` event. see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: How do I cast my value correctly? I got this as an error: `Conversion from type 'mat_edit_ascx' to type 'String' is not valid`

Comment: @bbesase, That's altogether separate question and not related to your initial question. I would suggest you to open a new post in SO for that (OR) check in MSDN. I don't have much idea about VB.NET but what's the type of `mat_edit_ascx`?

Comment: its just one of the web pages this person named... I just don't really know how to set this up, thanks for the point in the right direction though, I'll do some reading on it

Comment: @bbesase, as suggested post a new question with all related info. Again, no offense but don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.